# CSS: Not overwrite but reset to "normal"

Tags: css, css-selectors

I'm working on a website, and I stumbled on a issue I've been thinking about some time now.

Somewhere in the CSS-file I defined "Left: 12px" but afterwards some class'es overlap. I want to set "right: 25px" on the same object. But then I have to eliminate the "left"...

If this was a background, I could set it to "none", and then it was cleared - but is this possible to a "left"??

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is to set "Left" to "auto" ... okay, I have to go to bed now... :-/

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
left: auto;
```

Answer (score 3):

I think what you are looking for is:

left:auto;